# Effects of a nuke against a large ancient city

Tags: ancient-history

In my world, a mad scientist accidentally created a wormhole during the middle of a nuclear war, and a 15kt fission bomb flew through it and appeared in an ancient city around the size of 100$km^2$.

The city is based in the late Iron Ages and has multiple outposts a few kilometres away. The population is about 85000 people. If the nuke were to hit the very edge of the city, what catastrophes would occur and how might it change the current day timeline, assuming it was caused in the year 2300?

Comment: Without the specifics of the nuke how do you expect us to meaningfully answer this question. Can you provide any description about the city and its construction?

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix that right away! Tell me if I need to add anymore info!

Comment: If the city is iron age, what does the reference to 2300 mean? AD? Some other dating system? Also, iron age where? Britain? Mesopotamia? East Asia? How would they have made a nuke, let alone a wormhole, in the iron age? Just need some clarification!

Comment: Basically, 2300 is the year when the nuclear war occurs. It is the year when the bomb flies through into the wormhole and enters the past. @elemtilas

Comment: Okay that helps. You might also want to specify a location in space and time. I'd argue that if you hit a proto-Korean city 2100 years ago, the current time line would remain largely unchanged. If you hit Jerusalem on a certain day 20 centuries ago, human history might just be entirely rewritten. These are some things you might want to consider editing into your question, as right now, it's far too broad to be answered well.

Comment: https://www.deepspace.ucsb.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Effects-of-Nuclear-Weapons-1977-3rd-edition-complete.pdf This is the US Military's classic work on nukes. 650 pages on everything from what they do to bunker or even underground city design

Comment: @SeanOConnor That magnificent document just made it to the List of Worldbuilding Resources. Thanks for the resource! Anybody asking a question about nuclear bombs or blast effects should review that first before asking their question.

Comment: You're welcome. I hadn't read it for ages and I was wrong about the bunker/city design, but that's in its counterpart, something like Building Structures To Resist Nuclear Weapons. It has a fab section on what tradesmen you need; for some reason the fact that you need one barber and chair for every 200 people is ingrained in my memory!

Comment: TM5-858-7 and 8.

Comment: I would say asking what "present day" 2300 would look like with this having happened is too complex to answer, as we cannot meaningfully answer what 2300 would look like period.  Do you have any information _about_ 2300 in your world that might give a basis for what changes might occur?

Comment: I assume the "present day" there actually means 2023.  That is, scientists or whoever launch a nuke back in time from 2300, it explodes in the Iron Age, and then we look at the effects in 2023. 

It seems to me that it would be very difficult to guess what the overall effects would be without knowing where it landed. But there would definitely be at least one new religion, with an *extremely credible* evidence that their gods exist and will happily flatten a city for not-well-understood reasons.

Comment: @Zwuwdz It was due to the Xerspians I tell you mate! Those wicked ways they had! Good thing we holocausted every one of them. Good riddance!    (Always find a group of people you can blame, you are going to reap the fruits. - 101 of Governing)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Hiroshima-like device is going to have Hiroshima-like consequences. The iron-age houses are not going to be any less resistant that wood-and-paper houses were then, and the stone-built temples and public buildings are probably comparable to the concrete and steel constructions Hiroshima had.

A very important detail you've left out of the description is the height at which the bomb explodes. It's not the same if it's an airbust than if it explodes on ground level. Supposing an explosion of the optimal height for this kind of device, the amount of destruction would be comparable to the one Hiroshima suffered.

Main differences? The most populated city of the time would have been probably something like Mohenjo-Daro, and it was way smaller than your city, with half as much population. The other one is the lack of an organized service of firefighters. Many antique cities fell prey to fires which sprouted from a single incident to engulf whole sections of the city - even in a much modern period, cities such as London suffered similar fates. An atomic explosion is all but guaranteed to create enough different fires that we can be certain won't be put out in time to prevent fire to destroy the parts of the city the explosion hasn't destroyed first.

Obviously, and just like Hiroshima, the surviving inhabitants would have no knowledge about what befell on them, and would take no measure to protect themselves against fallout and radiation, so they would start dying from radiation sickness in the following hours and days. So, you end with the burnt remains of an abandoned city. Those survivors who didn't fled inmediately died of terrible diseases, thus confirming the theory that the city was destroyed by a vengeance by the gods, and the place would be abandoned and marked as an evil, doomed place, home to ghosts and bad spirits to avoid at any cost.

Answer (score 6):

### They're all dead... maybe...

In an article titled, "Counting the Dead at Hiroshima and Nagasaki," the Bulletin of the Atomic Scientists stated:

> **How many died?**
>
> The most credible estimates cluster around a “low” of 110,000 mortalities and a “high” of 210,000, an enormous gap. (The estimates for each city have a range of ±10,000.)
>
> There is no evidence that either of these estimates was made inaccurately or dishonestly, but they come from different sources and eras.
>
> **Low**
>
> 70,000 at Hiroshima + 40,000 at Nagasaki = 110,000 total
>
> Made by the US military  •  Issued in the 1940s  •  Emphasizes the military necessity of the attacks
>
> **High**
>
> 140,000 at Hiroshima + 70,000 at Nagasaki = 210,000 total
>
> Made by anti-nuclear weapons scientists  •  Largely spearheaded by Japan  •  Issued in the 1970s  •  Emphasizes the suffering of the Japanese. ([Source](https://thebulletin.org/2020/08/counting-the-dead-at-hiroshima-and-nagasaki/))

Referencing some simple statistics from the [Bradbury Science Museum](https://www.census.gov/history/pdf/fatman-littleboy-losalamosnatllab.pdf) we learn that Fat Man, the larger bomb (21Kt) destroyed less city than Little Boy (15Kt). What this really points out is that there a far more variables in play than just the size of the bomb. We know that air detonations are much more destructive than ground detonations. We know that geography plays a role. Etc.

We also know that population density plays a role. I believe the square-mile population density of Hiroshima and Nagasaki were much higher than the population density of any Iron-Age city.

But, probably much, much worse, even though the medical technologies available to the Japanese in the 1940s were archaic compared to today, it was godlike compared to the medical technologies of the iron age. Add to that no mechanization (aka ambulances, trucks), no substantial fire control, almost everything built out of wood... and the winds caused by a nuclear explosion.

**Conclusion**

If you're looking for "realistic," then I'm going with "they're all dead."

On the other hand, I believe it's reasonable for you to select some small number (less than 20%) of survivors as a function of [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609). In other words, it's perfectly believable if someone survived — you need only say so.

Answer (score 3):

If the nuke was detonated at ground level, you would not get the levelling of buildings you get with an airburst, but the fireball would suck up a lot of surface material with it, and make a lot of fallout.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upshot-Knothole_Harry

This was a 32 kT weapon detonated at the top of a 300 ft tower. The is as high as you might get in an ancient city. Your weapon is half the size than knothole-harry, but closer to the ground, so you would get less shockwave and flash damage, but more fallout. This would probably do for almost everyone within a few km, but some might last for weeks or months. If you want to have survivors, put them the other side of a small hill, upwind and upstream of the explosion. Have them stay underground for a day or two, so they miss the effects of the shorter half-life isotopes in the fallout.